# Interaction between application deployed in two different domain in GWT

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, cors

I have an application which contains the UI code created as WAR (`GWT` application) and server side code as `EAR` deployed in two different domains(`8080,9090`) respectively. While communicating from `8080`to`9090` its sending a request and even i can see its returning the response `200`. But the client is throwing some `GWT` exception **Permission denied to access property 'document' **. Below image shows the exception thrown in fire bug.

[image]

Note: i have enabled the CORS in server 9090 see the below code added in server side code EAR

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1,
            FilterChain arg2) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request=(HttpServletRequest) arg0;
        HttpServletResponse response=(HttpServletResponse) arg1;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
        arg2.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Is there any think i need to add in GWT client UI to handle this exception.Any suggestion ?

Comment: use `postMessage()`, you can't poke into the dom of a window on another domain, regardless of CORS settings...

Comment: thanks dandavis..where to use this postMessage()? war & ear deployed in  different domains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that you trying to make `AJAX GWT-RPC` request on the different domain/port? Even if you try to "cheat" it, it won't work in all browsers (it won't be cross-browser), because CORS is rather new solution that came with HTML5. 
Maybe you should consider using REST protocol to communicate between Client and Server? 
I had such problem when I had to communicate between different domain context from UI to Server and the only way was to use `REST` service. Cross browser solution.

If you want still to stick with breaking SOP and applying CORS try to change your filter according to this article: https://code.google.com/archive/p/gwtquery/wikis/Ajax.wiki

Like this:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

String origin = req.getHeader("Origin");
if (origin != null && origin.matches(ALLOWED_DOMAINS_REGEXP)) {
  resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
  if ("options".equalsIgnoreCase(req.getMethod())) {
    resp.setHeader("Allow", "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS");
    if (origin != null) {
      String headers = req.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
      String method = req.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method");
      resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", method);
      resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", headers);
      // optional, only needed if you want to allow cookies.
      resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    }
    resp.getWriter().flush();
    return;
  }
}

// Fix ios6 caching post requests
if ("post".equalsIgnoreCase(req.getMethod())) {
  resp.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
}

if (filterChain != null) {
  filterChain.doFilter(req, resp);
}

}
```

And don't forget to configure the filter properly:

```
    <filter> 
 <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name> 
<filter-class>my.namespace.CORSFilter</filter-class> 
</filter> 

<filter-mapping> 
<filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name> 
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: still i am getting the same exception in firefox..but in chrome its throwing this exception Uncaught com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: (TypeError) 
 __gwt$exception: <skipped>: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null..any suggestion

Comment: How about IE? Mark my answer up if that helped:)

Comment: thanks mlewandowski for your answer..i m able to solve this issue with this hint(+1)..

Comment: Great to hear! Cheers!